# Get LatLng given a point

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am referencing some locations on Google Maps (by loading JSON data using AJAX) and then i store those points in an array, then i link some markers with each other and store the polylines in an array as well.

Now i am attempting to filter some markers (given their name), i retrieve the corresponding marker (or point) from the previous list, and i perform a loop over all the polylines to get the ones that have the latter point as start or end.
The problem is that i get from the polyline only the coordinates of the start and the end using this function `polyline.getPath().getAt(indiceLoop);` , and i need to compare this to the point's coordinate.

So, is there a way to get coordinates LatLng given an already created point?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You mean get the coordinates of a marker given a reference to it ([google.maps.Marker.getPosition](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker))?  How is the "already created point" saved?

Comment: the points are saved into the array while i am creating the markers and inserting them into the map (at each loop)
i'll try your suggestion and be back in a minute :)

Comment: actually the function : polyline.getPath().getAt(indiceLoop); is returning something like this (5.60518980026245, -0.16678600013256073)
whereas marker.getPosition() returns an object !!
how can i check if the point represents the start or end of the polyline given this ??

Comment: The function polyline.getPath().getAt(indiceLoop) is returning a google.maps.LatLng, just like marker.getPosition does.  To compare two LatLngs objects, I usually compute the distance between them, if the distance is small enough, then they are the same.

Comment: yeah you're right , it is returning an object.
concerning the distance, how would you compute it ? i thought about comparing lat and lng and say that they are the same in case they are equal !!

Comment: [google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical)

Comment: will try this tomorrow and give a feedback ...
thanks

Comment: Please post enough of your code to give an intelligent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume a google.maps.Marker ("marker") and a google.maps.Polyline ("polyline").  Not tested.

```
if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(marker.getPosition(),polyline.getPath().getAt(0)) < 0.1) {
  // marker is at start of polyline
  alert("marker at start");
} else if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(marker.getPosition(),polyline.getPath().getAt(polyline.getPath().getLength()-1)) < 0.1) {
  // marker is at end of polyline
  alert("marker at end");
}
```

Comment: i voted for your answer and accepted it because what i needed initially was to get a point's coordinates, and you suggested the getPosition() function

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up using marker.getPosition().equals(line.getpath().getAt())and the same for the line end and it worked fine !!

Thanks for your proposition :)